# Queen puzzle 4x4

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this Queen problem of placing 4 queen in 4x4 matrix . I know it can be solved with backtracking algorithm . However i have not studied that and i am trying to solve it with my current knowledge . So what i am trying is to generate all possible combination of Queen in 4x4 matrix and print only one which cannot cancel each other .

1) For generating all combination , i am using rand function .

However there is obviously fault in my above coding . There are some outputs with only three '1' instead of four '1' . I am not able to eliminate this problem .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ar[30][30], i , j , a , b , c = -1, d = -1, k = 0;  

    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)
            {
                ar[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
            {
                a = rand() % 3 ;
                b = rand() % 3 ;
                if (a != c || b != d)
                {
                    ar[a][b] =  1 ; // here 1 = Queen 
                    c = a ;
                    d = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

2) Also is there any way i can reduce the time complexity using only these method ?

Comment: "Randomly generating all combinations" in your code is a bad idea as you will run the chance of never generating the solution.

Comment: @Paul I agree that there should be also a different solution, but if the random number generator is uniform, it might not be the fastest but probably in the long run it might (should) work too ... I assume that indeed the problem might be that a unique generator is used for both a and b ..

Comment: Can't you use permutations and a recursive function? If you put the queens in the diagonal, then you do all permutation on the lets say top/right corner: 2x2 , and store them, then you switch the indexes 2,3 and use the previously stored permutation ... and so on.. mmm.. I will be curious to calculate the scaling ... but for 4x4 maybe it is still reasonable. On the other side if you want to print them, the number of permutation should not be that high ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using temporary variables to check whether the array is filled, use the array itself!

```
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
        {
            a = rand() % 3 ;
            b = rand() % 3 ;
            if (ar[a][b] == 0)
            {
                ar[a][b] =  1 ; // here 1 = Queen 
            }
        }
    }
```

Your problem is that the inner loop will execute 4 times and you can only control 1 repeat with variables `c` and `d`.

Let's say `a` is 1 and `b` is 1: you make `c = 1` and `d = 1`.

then `a` is 2 and `b` is 1 ... making `c = 2` and `d = 1`.

then if a is 1 and b is 1 again, you cannot check for duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You check only that a queen isn't placed on the same square as the last queen you placed. Remove the variables `c` and `d` and check whether `ar[a][b]` is still zero.

(2) Your scatter approach will produce many set-ups that are misses. Especially, because you don't enforce that ther cannot be any queens on the same rank and file. (In addition, `rand() % 3` produces random values from 0 to 2, inclusively. You will never get a non-threatening configuration that way.)

If you want to use your random ([bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)) approach, you could use a one-dimensional array where the index is the rank and the number is the file where a queen is. Then you start with:

```
int queen[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

and shuffle the array. For 4 queens, that will yield 4! = 24 possibile configurations. You could try to iterate through them systematically.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the brute force, backtracking code for the 8 queens problem, asked some time ago. Just change 8 to 4:

```
int checkBoard(int board[8][8]);
int putQueens(int board[8][8], int nQueens);
void printBoard(int board[8][8]);

int eightQueens(void)
{
    int board[8][8];
    memset(board, 0, sizeof(int)*64);
    if (putQueens(board, 0)) {
        printBoard(board);
        return (1);
    }
    return(0);
}


int putQueens(int board[8][8], int nQueens)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]==0) {
                board[i][j]= 1;
                if (checkBoard(board)) {
                    if (nQueens==7) return(1);
                    if (putQueens(board, nQueens+1)) return(1);
                }
                board[i][j]= 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
int checkBoard(int board[8][8])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                int ii, jj;
                for (ii=i+1; ii<8; ii++) {
                    if (board[ii][j]) return(0);
                }
                for (jj=j+1; jj<8; jj++) {
                    if (board[i][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i+1, jj=j+1; ii<8 && jj<8; ii++, jj++) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i-1, jj=j-1; ii>0 && jj>0; ii--, jj--) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i-1, jj=j+1; ii>0 && jj<8; ii--, jj++) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i+1, jj=j-1; ii<8 && jj>0; ii++, jj--) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (1);
}
void printBoard(int board[8][8])
{
    int i,j;
    printf("  ");
    for (j=0; j<8; j++) printf(" %1d",j+1); printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("%1d ",i+1);
        for (j=0; j<8; j++)
            printf(" %1c", board[i][j]==0? '-':'*');
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```